# Prove or disprove: If $1=||A||>||B||$, then $A-B$ is nonsingular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

Prove or disprove: If $1=\|A\|>\|B\|$, then $A-B$ is nonsingular.

I think that since $\|A-B\|>0$ by the given conditions we know it is nonsingular. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about $A = \operatorname{diag}(1, 0)$ and $B = 0$?

Comment: What is $diag(1,0)$?

Comment: It's the 2 by 2 diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $1$ and $0$.

Comment: oh ok, I see now

Answer (score 1):

As stated, this is false, since even $A$ itself could be singular under the given assumptions. To conclude that $A-B$ is nonsingular when $B$ is "small", one needs:

1. $A$ to be nonsingular
2. $\|B\| < \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$

The reason this works is that $\|A^{-1}\|^{-1} = \min_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|$. Hence, assumption 2 implies $\|Bx\|<\|Ax\|$ for all $x$, making $Ax-Bx=0$ impossible.

There is no improvement on 2. in general. There is a matrix $B$ such that $\|B\| = \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$; it can be constructed as a rank-one matrix that maps $x$ to $Ax$ for a specific $x$ that attains $\min_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|$.